# What is result of comparison of double and NaN?

Tags: c++, c++11, nan

I have the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    double a = 1;
    double b = nan("");

    std::cout << (a > b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (b > a) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
0
```

In general from the meaning of `nan` - `not a number` it is clear that any operation with `nan` is essentially pointless. From `IEEE-754` that I found in internet I found what if in FPU at least one of operands is `nan` the result is also `nan`, but I found nothing about comparison between normal value and `nan` as in example above.

What does standard say about it?

Comment: The FPU functions and the logical result of a comparison are probably two different things. What does your disassembly say?

Comment: Your code might (or might not) be missing a `==` comparison. You did check for `<` and `>` but not for `==`. Maybe you meant to use `<` and `>=` or `<=` and `>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What does standard say about it?

The C++ standard does not say how operations on NaNs behave. It is left unspecified. So, as far as C++ is concerned, any result is possible and allowed.

ANSI/IEEE Std 754–1985 says:

> 5.7. Comparison
>
> ... Every NaN shall compare  unordered with everything, including itself. ...

What *unordered* means exactly is shown in the Table 4 in the same section. But in short, this means that the comparison shall return false, if any of the operands is NaN, except `!=` shall return true.

Answer (score 2):

The 0 you're seeing means `false` in this case as that's what the stream shows for false by default. If you want to see it as `true` or `false` use `std::boolalpha`:

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << (a > b) << std::endl;
```

Whey comparing floating point values where one of the values is nan then `x<y`, `x>y`, `x<=y`, `x>=y`, and `x==y` will all evaluate to false, whereas `x!=y` will always be true. Andrew Koenig has a good article on this on the [Dr Dobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/its-hard-to-compare-floating-point-numbe/240149806) website.

When you think about it the result cannot be `nan` since comparison operators need to return a boolean which can only have 2 states.

Comment: Can you provide any reference where this behavior defined (I mean comparison operation between NaN and any other normal value)?

Comment: @Alex - I've provided a link to an article

Answer (score 1):

0 here means false.
Nan is not equal or comparable to any value so the result of operation is false(0).

Comment: What you say is pretty logical, but can you give any reference where it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Well, on top of @user2079303 pretty good answer, there are two NaNs: quiet NaN and signaling NaN. You could check `std::numeric_limits<T>::has_signaling_NaN` on your platform is signaling NaN is available. If it is true and value contains `std::numeric_limits<T>::signaling_NaN`, then

> When a signaling NaN is used as an argument to an arithmetic expression, the appropriate floating-point exception may be raised and the NaN is "quieted", that is, the expression returns a quiet NaN.

To really get FP exception you might want to set FPU control word (for x87 unit) or MXCSR register (for SSE2+ unit). This is true for x86/x64 platform, check your platform docs for similar functionality